# Spoofing smartphone sensordata using a wearable's sensordata to make use of the Google activity recognition api

Tags: android, android-activity, sensors, detection, microsoft-band

I would like to the test the accuracy of the Google Activity Recognition api using a wearable's sensordata. I can register my android application to listen to sensorevents (I'm using the Microsoft band 2) and would like to know if there is a way to make the application / google play services think the sensordata is coming from my smartphone. I'm not very familiar with how the google api exactly works and in which way it accesses my smartphone's sensordata.